# Function to check if column names are unique

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working on a program and now I'm looking for a way to check the column names when uploading a file. If the names are not unique an error should be written. Is there any way to do this?

For example if I have these df:

```
> a <- c(10, 20, 30)
> b <- c(1, 2, 3)
> c <- c("Peter", "Ann", "Mike")
> test <- data.frame(a, b, c)
```

with:

```
library(dplyr)
test <- rename(test, Number = a)
test <- rename(test, Number = b)
> test
  Number Number     c
1     10      1 Peter
2     20      2   Ann
3     30      3  Mike
```

If this were a file how could I check if the column names are unique. Nice would be as result only True or False!

Thanks!

Comment: try this: `sum(duplicated(colnames(test)))>0`

Comment: `length(unique(colnames(test)) == length(colnames(test))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test.frame <- data.frame(a = c(1:5), b = c(6:10))
a <- c(5:1)
test.frame  <- cbind(test.frame, a)

## Build data.frame with duplicate column

test.unique <- function(df) {  ## function to test unique columns

  length1 <- length(colnames(df))
  length2 <- length(unique(colnames(df)))        
  if (length1 - length2 > 0 ) {

    print(paste("There are", length1 - length2, " duplicates", sep=" "))
  }     
}
```

This results in ...

```
test.unique(test.frame)
```

[1] "There are 1  duplicates"

Answer (score 5):

We can use:

```
any(duplicated(names(df))) #tested with df as iris
[1] FALSE
```

On OP's data:

```
any(duplicated(names(test)))
[1] TRUE
```

The above can be simplified using the following as suggested by @sindri_baldur and @akrun

```
anyDuplicated(names(test))
```

If you wish to know how many are duplicated:

```
length(which(duplicated(names(test))==TRUE))
[1] 1
```

This can also be simplified to(as suggested by @sindri_baldur:

```
sum(duplicated(names(test)))
```

Comment: `length(which(duplicated(names(test))==TRUE))` can be simplified to `sum(duplicated(names(test)))` and `any(duplicated(names(test)))` can be simplified to `anyDuplicated(names(test))`

Comment: I'm not sure why I abandoned `sum` but now that I think of it, it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: There is also `anyDuplicated`

Comment: Edited to add all the options. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check for the functions `unique()` and `colnames()`. For example:

```
are.unique.colnames <- function(array){
  return(length(unique(colnames(array))) == dim(array)[2])
}
```

is a function based on the number of different column names (a easy and useful metadata of any array-like structure)