# Have read.table give a warning with duplicate names in R?

Tags: r

Is there a way to have `read.table` warn the user when there are duplicate names in a file? E.g.,

```
test1 <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=6:10,a=11:15, check.names = FALSE)
tf <- tempfile()
write.csv(test1, tf,row.names = FALSE)

read.csv(tf) # throw a warning about the column name `a`
```

Comment: `data.frame` doesn't allow duplicate names.  It is just a warning

Comment: Yeah. I know. What I'd like is for the user to be alerted that they tried to read in a file that has duplicate names.

Comment: If you check the data.frame  created (test1), it is already having name changed with `make.unique`.  While construcitng the example, you need `check.names = FALSE` i.e. `test1 <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=6:10,a=11:15, check.names = FALSE)`

Comment: You could read it in and then check after the fact: [Function to check if column names are unique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55969534/8366499)

Comment: I think what I want to do is scan the first line of the file to look for repeats before invoking read.table (or read.csv). E.g., scan(tf,nlines=1,what = "char",sep=",")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to add in a `scan` to read the first line of the file which will allow me to wrap `read.table` in a function to warn the user if there are any duplicates in the column names.

```
checkNames <- scan(tf,nlines=1,what = "char",sep=",")
any(duplicated(checkNames))
```